# Tutte polynomials and related graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm very new to this subject of Tutte polynomials and I have the following question which has probably no general answer but maybe in particular cases?

Let $$T(G;x,y) = \sum_{A \subseteq E(G)} (x-1)^{\mathrm{rk}(G)-\mathrm{rk}(A)} (y-1)^{\mathrm{null}(A)}$$ be the [Tutte polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_polynomial) in 2 variables x and y of the graph G.

Let $A(n,m)$ a sequence  of real numbers (typical example I'm interested in is binomial coefficients $B(2n,m)$ or even the central binomials $B(2n,n)$)

Is it reasonable to try to find a graph $G$ whose Tutte polynomial evaluated at certain couples gives back the $A(n,m)$ ( or at least the diagonal $A(n,n)$ ) sequence?

For example $T(K_n;2,0) = n!$ where $K_n$ is the complete graph on $n$ vertices
or $T(K_n;2,2) = 2^{B(n,2)}$  where $B$ is the binomial coefficient.

Any good introductory text reference is welcome

Thanks in advance for any answer.
Gianfranco

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question: as a polynomial, the Tutte polynomial grows polynomially as $x,y \rightarrow \infty$.  However, the central binomial coefficient grows exponentially.  So, you'd also need the graph $G$ to be a parameter (like in the $T(K_n;2,2)$ case); either that or map $(n,m)$ to other points in the plane (but this would result in trivial answers since e.g. $T(K_2;x,y)=x$).

Comment: Thanks Douglas. Yes you are right. IT would be just great If I could find a sequence of graphs Gn such that T(Gn;2,2)= B(2n,n)